# Default subnet not found

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I run `terraform apply` with the resource:

```
 resource "aws_default_subnet" "my_az_default_subnet" {
    availability_zone = "eu-north-1"
}
```

I get the error:

```
aws_default_subnet.learntf_default_subnet: Creating...
Error: Default subnet not found
```

even if the default VPC and subnet exists in the specified `availability_zone` "eu-north-1".

---

`provider.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = var.aws_access_key
    secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
    region = "eu-north-1"
}
```

`variables.tf`:

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}
```

`network.tf`:

```
resource "aws_default_subnet" "learntf_default_subnet" {
    availability_zone = "eu-north-1"
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the default subnet exists before or after the `apply`?

Comment: The default subnet exists before the `apply`

Comment: According to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-subnet, you can only have on default subnet per AZ, so this would definitely fail. Is your issue that the error message is not as clear as you would like?

Comment: According to terraform documentation: 

"The aws_default_subnet behaves differently from normal resources, in that Terraform does not create this resource, but instead "adopts" it into management."
(https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_subnet.html)
So I would expect terraform to apply the specified resource, with no error, without creating it, and adopting it into management.

Comment: You likely need to import it into your state first then.

Comment: Just by declaring the resource:
`resource "aws_default_subnet" "learntf_default_subnet" {
    availability_zone = "eu-north-1"
}`
should import it into the state. This is exactly what is failing.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake. It worked with.

```
resource "aws_default_subnet" "def_subnet" {
    availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
}
```